# ASP.NET MVC: How to send the ids of the DOM Body elements on the client's browser TO the controller when navigating from the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app (ASP.NET NOT ASP.NET Core).

When a View is rendered, the user can click on some buttons on the page to collapse or show divs associated with each button. The div changes its class depending on whether it is collapsed or shown. I am using bootstrap attributes for this, and it works fine.

Now I have a "Save" button on the page. When the user clicks on this button, I need to retrieve the ids and classes of the divs, and pass them TO the Controller (in an array/collection/dictionary whatever).

Is there a way/method in ASP.NET to send to the Controller the attributes (ids, classes, etc) of the DOM elements on the client's browser ?

Thanks

Comment: use ajax and jquery to do it, use jquery to get ids + classes and use ajax to send it to controller.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how to do it in ASP.NET? I know a little bit of JAVA. I can write a code to get elements by class/Id, etc. But how to get this information passed to the controller when the user clicks? Thanks.

Comment: create class name ViewModel: contain id and elements, in controller param will be: List<ViewModel>, and in view ajax send list of id and elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send some attributes of DOM to Controller, I have a way.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="demo-1" class="chosendiv other-className" data-code ="abc">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="demo-2" class="chosendiv other-className" data-code ="xyz">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="demo-3" class="other-className" data-code ="mnt">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<button id="btn-save" onclick="Save()">SAVE</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        function Save(){
             var cds = document.getElementsByClassName('chosendiv');
             var finder = [];

             if(cds != null){
                for(i = 0; i< cds.length; i++){
                    finder.push({
                        ID: cds[i].getAttribute('id'),
                        ClassName: cds[i].getAttribute('class'),
                        Code: cds[i].getAttribute('data-code')
                    })
                }
             }

            //
            // Send finder to Controller. You can use Ajax... 
            // A simple ajax call:
            //
            $.ajax({
                  url: '/Home/YourAction',
                  type: 'GET', //<---- you can use POST method.
                  data:{
                       myDiv: JSON.stringify(finder)
                  },
                  success: function(response){
                         // Your code
                  }
            })

        }
</script>
```

**Your Controller**

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
     public HomeController(){}

     [HttpGet]
     public void YourAction(string myDiv)
     {
          
        //A lot of ways for converting string to Object, such as: creating new class for model, ...
        // I use Dictionary Class
     
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> temp = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myDiv))
        {
           try
           {
              temp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(myDiv);
           }
           catch { // Do something if it catches error. }
        }

        // Get a element (at index) from temp if temp.Count()>0
        // var id = temp.ElementAt(index)["ID"];
        // var className = temp.ElementAt(index)["ClassName"];
        // var code = temp.ElementAt(index)["Code"];

        //
        //Your code
        //
        
     }

     //......
}
```

It would be great if my answer could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is great especially the Ajax function. However, it does not resolve my problem. After many trials, I found that in my case the URL generated is too long. I tried to replace the json format with a simple string to compact the url. Still too long. Cannot rely on urls in my case. Need to pass an object (an array). I need the object in the body of a post request to be captured by the controller. I vaguely know that the controller class can parse the request info from the "context" object. I will try to pass to parse the body of a post request. In all cases the ajax

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided by @Gia Khang

I made few changes in order to avoid the issue of the length of the URL exceeding the maximum limit.

Instead of adding the element's classes to an array using JS, I add them to a string :

function Save() {

```
    var cds = document.getElementsByClassName('chosendiv');
    // I use as string instead of an array
    var finder = "";

     if(cds != null){
        for(i = 0; i< cds.length; i++){
        finder = finder + "id=" + cds[i].getAttribute('id') + "class=" + cds[i].getAttribute('class') + "data-code=" +cds[i].getAttribute('data-code')

        }
     }
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                        
        // Send finder to Controller. You can use Ajax...
        // A simple ajax call:

        var myURL = "/{Controller}/{Action}"

        $.ajax({
            url: myURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: { ids:finder },                                                            
               success: function (response) {
                }
            })
    }
```

In the Controller Action I add a parameter named "ids" (this must be the same name as the identifier of the data object in the post request)and I extract the id, class, and data value from the ids string by a method in one of my Models classes (sorry I work with VB.NET not with C# and it will take me a lot of time to convert the code to C#. I use the Split method in VB to split the ids string several times: a first one by using "id=" as delimiter, then spiting each element in the resulting array by the second delimiter "class=", etc. I add the resulting elements to a collection)

The Controller Action looks like this:

```
    public class HomeController: Controller
    {
         public HomeController(){}
    
         [HttpPost]
         public void YourAction(string ids)
         {
              
            Models.myClass.splitStringMethod(ids)
Return View()
}


    }
```